# Dividing two polynomials in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math, polynomials

I'm currently working on a Cyclic Code program for a class in MATLAB and I'm trying to figure out the best way to divide two polynomials, the generator P(X) and the user input, shifted by 3 (x^3 * D(X)) in order to get the Quotient Q(X) and Remainder C(X), which would allow me to get the transmitted data T(X) = X^3*D(X) + C(X)

The code I have for my program so far takes in the users 4-bit input in binary, i.e.

```
Insert 4-bit input: 1001
```

Then it checks it to make sure its valid, and shifts it giving:

```
0 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

which stands for the polynomial

```
X^3 + X^6
```

I then need to divide that by the generator polynomial

```
P(X) = 1 + X + X^3
```

Working it out on paper,

```
x^6 + X^3
___________
x^3 + x + 1 

Gives: Q(X) = X^3 + X 
       R(X) = X^2 + X

So, T(X) = X^6 + X^3 + X^2 + X, which is 0111001 for the Codeword
```

What would be the best way to do this?

I have tried the following:

```
% Prompt for User input
b4_in = input('Insert 4-bit input: ' ,'s'); %Input 1001

%% CHECK FOR VAILD INPUT %%

dec_in = bin2dec(b4_in)

bin_in = fliplr(de2bi(dec_in)) %User input in Binary

d = [0000000];  %Calculating X^3 * D(X)
d = bin_in;
d(7)=0;
d = fliplr(d); %Gives 0 0 0 1 0 0 1

d

gen_pol = [1 1 0 1] %P(X) = 1 + X + X^3

[q, c] = deconv(bin_in, gen_pol)
```

When I go this, I get:

```
q =

     1


c =

     0    -1     0     0
```

What do I need to do differently to get the following?

```
q = 0 1 0 1

c = 0 1 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: I tried their solution and the outcome is not exactly what I need. I updated my question with that information

Comment: I think the simplest solution is to have the binary digit entered as an array or ones and zeroes since that's how Matlab numerically handles polynomials.

Comment: Well, the way I did it, it still converts the user input to an array of 1s and 0s so that shouldn't affect what needs to be done to do the division right?

Comment: Except they're characters and not numbers.  The best way to do this in Matlab is with numbers (i.e., the user inputs `[1,0,0,1]`) and avoid `dec2bin` since Matlab doesn't have a bit data type and all operations are either with doubles or integers.

Comment: Oh, Ok! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB, polynomials read in a binary vector from left to right. For example, x^3+x is [1 0 1 0], x^2+x is [1 1 0]. The Quotient Q(X) should be x^3-x instead of x^3+x. Make sure your inputs are in the right format, and you should get the following result as expected,

q =

```
 1     0    -1     0
```

c =

```
 0     0     0     0     1     1     0
```

Comment: Oh, from all the things I have read, I thought it was the opposite order, [1, x, x^2, x^3, etc...] Thanks!